# Can we do Load testing for Video or Audio call in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

Is there any way we can do performance testing for voice or video call ? Jmeter or any other open source tools provide anything ? Please reommend any tool if we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)) which is being used under the hood of the video and/or audio call.

First of all you need to determine which protocol(s) is (are) used by your application. It can be done using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Once you know the protocol(s) you should be able to check whether JMeter (or other open source tool) supports this protocol or not.

The options could be in:

1. JMeter supports the protocol out of the box via one of its [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers). For example if the protocol is simple enough and can be recorded and replayed you can capture the requests using the aforementioned Wireshark and simulate them with the [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler), however the chance it will work is minimal
2. JMeter supports the protocol via one of its [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
3. There is a Java (or other language) client library implementing the protocol, in this case you will be able to use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and implement the use cases in Groovy (or other language, but it has to be [JVM/JSR223 compabitle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages)) or [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/) sampler and implement the use cases in Java
4. The protocol is proprietary and there are no client libraries for it. In this case you won't be able to conduct the load test without reaching out to the call system vendor and asking them for the implementation details and instructions on how it can be tested.

Comment: thanks for all details, well is there other tool ? any paid tool that provide all these type of testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UBIK Load Pack](https://ubikloadpack.com/) which is a paid version for load test videos using JMeter with free trail

> Realistic and Scalable Load Testing for MPEG Dash, Apple's HTTP Live, Microsoft Smooth and Adobe HDS Streaming formats